# Two conditions for DO WHILE loop in C

Tags: c, do-while

Could you please explain me why this condition works with `||` and does not with `&&`.

I fixed this on my own. I just do not understand why this is `OR` and not `AND`.

This program must quit the loop when user inputs `Q0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    char character;
    int integer;
    
    printf("Loop started\n\n");
    
    do {
        printf("Enter Q0 to quit the loop: ");
        scanf(" %c%d", &character, &integer);
        
        if (character != 'Q' || integer != 0) {
            printf("Invalid value(s)!\n\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Correct value(s)!\n");
        }

    } while (character != 'Q' || integer != 0);
   
    printf("\nLoop ended\n");
   
    return 0;
}
```

[Code link](https://onlinegdb.com/PoUm3LCpb)

Comment: How is it supposed to work? How does it not work?

Comment: Evaluate the expression step by step (`character != 'Q' && integer != 0` -> `true && false` -> `false`) on an input where it produces a wrong answer, and think about why that is.

Comment: @Haris It works. I'm asking for an explanation. Why does it work?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of @Haris' question. Define what "works" means. Give example inputs and outputs that you are seeing. How do those outputs line up (or not) with what you expected to happen

Comment: || means or and && means and.  Not sure what explanation you are looking for.  One way to look at loops is the condition is false when done which means `!(character != 'Q' || interger != 0)` => `character == 'Q' && integer == 0`

Comment: Check the return value of scanf() otherwise  either or both variables may be uninitialized.

Comment: @sedavidw This program must quit the loop when user inputs Q0

Comment: Look up [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  Think about reversing the loop condition: `if (character == 'Q' && integer == 0) print("Correct values!\n"); else printf("Invalid values!\n");` — it's simple to see it is correct.  Apply that condition in the loop with `while (!(character == 'Q' && integer == 0)`.  Then apply De Morgan to negate things (if you must — the version shown is simple and "obviously correct").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct and the loop will be exited if and only if the user enters a `Q` followed by a integer with a value of `0`. The test `(character != 'Q' || integer != 0)` is equivalent to `!(character == 'Q' && integer == 0)`. In plain English, the latter is a more direct translation of *continue unless the user typed a `Q` **and** the number `0`*.

Note however these remarks:

- using a `do` / `while` loop makes you repeat the test inside the loop at as the exit condition. It would be simpler to user a `for (;;)` loop, aka *for ever* loop, and use a `break` statement to exit the loop explicitly when the user types the appropriate sequence, using a positive test.
- you do not check the `scanf()` return value, which must be `2` for proper operation. If the user types a sequence that cannot be parsed with `" %c%d"`, the behavior may be incorrect and possibly undefined. For example an input of `10QA` will be misinterpreted as a correct value. It is much more reliable to read the input as a string with `fgets()`, parse it with `sscanf` and check the return values.
- `%d` will convert sequences such as   `00`, `+0` and `-0` as the number `0` which may or may not be expected. If the input sequence must match `Q0` exactly, the test must be performed some other way.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    printf("Loop started\n\n");
    
    for (;;) {
        char buf[128];
        char character, c2;
        int integer;

        printf("Enter Q0 to quit the loop: ");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, sizeof buf)) {
            printf("Unexpected end of file!\n\n");
            break;
        }
        if (sscanf(" %c%d %c", &character, &integer, &c2) != 2) {
            printf("Invalid format: must have a character and an integer!\n\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (character == 'Q' && integer == 0) {
            printf("Correct values!\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("Invalid values: %c%d!\n\n", character, integer);
        printf("Try again.\n");
    }
   
    printf("\nLoop ended\n");
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have learned a few new tricks. Right now I'm not allowed to use  `fgets` or `sscanf` as a part of this workshop, but I will definitely use these in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (character != 'Q' || integer != 0) {
    printf("Invalid value(s)!\n\n");
}
else {
    printf("Correct value(s)!\n");
}
```

These statements translate to:

*"If `character` is not equal to `Q` OR if `integer` is not equal to `0`, print invalid value.
Else, print correct value."*

So, if `character` is `Q` or `integer` is `0`, the expression will evaluate to `true` and correct value would be printed.

> Could you please explain me why this condition works with || and does
> not with &&.

Because if the first operand of the logical AND operator evaluates to false, the second operator is not evaluated. So if `character` is not equal to `Q`, then the second expression is never evaluated (even if `integer` is 0).

If the above code was written as:

```
if (character != 'Q' && integer != 0) {
     printf("Invalid value(s)!\n\n");
} else {
     printf("Correct value(s)!\n");
}
```

which translates to:
*"If `character` is not equal to `Q` AND `integer` is not equal to `0`, print incorrect value. Else, print correct value.*"

It'll only print correct value when the input was `Q0` and both the expressions evaluated to `true`.

Comment: You say "NB that if the first operand of the logical OR operator evaluates to false, the second operator is not evaluated".  That's incorrect — if the first operand evaluates to false, the second operator _is_ evaluated.  If the operator is logical AND, then if the first operand is false, the second is not evaluated.  And if the first operand of the logical OR operator evaluates to _true_, the second is _not_ evaluated.

Comment: You say "The above code snippet can be rewritten as" and then give an expression which is not equivalent to the first — which makes it unclear why you've rewritten it as shown.  If you replaced the `||` with `&&` in the second snippet, then you'd have an equivalent expression.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed. I fixed that. But I believe ```if (character == 'Q' || integer == 0) {
    printf("Correct value.\n");
} else {
    printf("Incorrect value\n");
}``` is equivalent to writing ```if (character != 'Q' || integer != 0) {
    printf("Invalid value(s)!\n\n");
}
else {
    printf("Correct value(s)!\n");
}``` Or perhaps I missed the point of OP's question, and *"I just do not understand why this is OR and not AND."* is rather unclear.

Comment: Suppose the input is Q3 or Z0.  The test `if (character == ‘Q’ || integer == 0)` will evaluate to true for both of those, even though neither is Q0 which is supposed to be the only acceptable input.

Comment: @Jonathan I see now what you're trying to say. But OP's statements: *"This program must quit the loop when user inputs Q0*" and *"this condition works with || and does not with &&."* are self-contradictory. OP believes the code is correct as is, even if the only acceptable input is ```Q0``` and his code accepts ```A0``` as valid. :)

Comment: Questions are allowed to have mistakes in them — answers should avoid replicating those mistakes when possible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'd keep that in mind next time. :)

Comment: @Haris I just checked `A0` . It prints `Invalid value(s)!` and does not quit the loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: Without seeing the changes you made to the code, it's hard to say assume what you're missing.